# How to combine MVC4 with EF5 Db First separate project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5, ef-database-first

In my solution I have two projects. One is the main **MVC4 project**. The other is a **DataLayer project** which contains an Entity Framework 5 edmx model generated from an existing DB (and maybe some Repositories later).

The problem is that the pocos EF5 generates sits in the DataLayer project. But I need them inside the Models folder in the MVC4 project.

I want the seperate DataLayer project to increase abstraction and separation of concerns, but I can't figure out how to put those two pieces together.
(I thought to maintain another layer of pocos in the Models folder but this dose not seems right)

Comment: Why do you 'need' them in the MVC4 project?   EF is going to generate those classes in the same assembly that the .edmx is created.  If you need to access those models, remember to add a reference to your data project from the MVC4 project.  Then you can reference the models Data.EntityObjectName (or however your namespaces work)

Comment: @Tommy Yes, but those classes dose not sit in the Models folder. One disadvantage is that Visual Studio won't recognize them in the 'Add View' dialog, as models to choose from. Maybe there are other disadvantages. The Models folder is a crucial part in the order MVC4 template tries to create. It does not seems right to me to leave it empty.

Comment: @YaronLevi I usually leave that model field blank when generating a view that way. It takes too long to scroll and I already know the full namespace of the model I want. So I just declare it manually at the top of the view. `@model FullNamespace.ViewModel`

Comment: Yes they will indeed show up in that drop down list, you just need to recompile the data project before you add or remove any changes to your Data project Models.

Comment: Sure. This is a very minor issue. I just mentioned it as a warning sign for leaving the models folder empty - you are not going along with the pattern.

Comment: If you are going to separate your project into 2-3 projects (MVC4WebLayer, BusinessLayer and Datalayer), make sure that you are using an IoC such as Ninject. It will make your life easier.

Comment: If you consider your EF models as domain models, the next step will be more clear to you, I think. Let EF do it's thing in your domain project and then let your mvc4 project's repos build some client friendly models. This allows you to have a separate model for decorating for the view, etc, and allows you to keep your domain models separate. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I have my projects separated into two as you describe.

> I thought to maintain another layer of pocos in the Models folder but this dose not seems right

I think you will find you will build this layer eventually.

Here's two projects **Project.Data** and **Project.Web**. Project.Web has a project reference to Project.Data.

- Project.Data.Models: Entities
- Project.Web.Models: DTOs, ViewModels

My views never directly reference Entities. I will map Entities to DTOs or ViewModels using AutoMapper. This happens in my *services* which sits in *Project.Web* under its own namespace. My services never return Entity types and my views use only ViewModels.

```
interface IFooService
{
    FooDTO GetFoo(int id);
}

public class FooService : IFooService
{
    public FooDTO GetFoo(int id)
    {
        var foo = dbContext.Foo.Where(f => f.Id == id).Select(f => new FooDTO {
            Bar = f.Bar,
            Blah = f.Blah
        }).FirstOrDefault();
        // I let AutoMapper take care of the mapping for me
        var foo = Mapper.Map<FooDTO>(dbContext.Foo.Where(f => f.Id == id).FirstOrDefault());

        return foo;
    }
}
```

Controller Action:

```
public ActionResult FooDetails(int id)
{
    FooViewModel foo = Mapper.Map<FooViewModel>(fooService.GetFoo(id));
    return View(foo);
}
```

**Edit:**
Added anther model layer to map Entity => DTO => View Model

Comment: This works although you shouldnt be returning view model from the data layer. You should return the model that EF5 generates or better yet a DTO object and then map that to a view model in the controller

Comment: @Ryan I am not returning view model from the data layer. In this example the service is not my data layer but encapsulates my business logic. Here EF is the data layer.

Comment: Sorry I shouldn't have said data layer, but regardless the view model should ONLY be created at the controller level. Think about it. If FooService was to be called by an iOS client the view model might be completely different.

Comment: @Ryan I think given the simplicity of this architecture it is debatable weather my services return DTOs or "ViewModels". Do you advocate one view model per view?

Comment: You are probably right, but I thought for the effort why not :P

Answer (score 0):

This is the job of the repository. Create DTO classes to hold view friendly models and use the repository to call your data layer and assemble the dto. The dtos can then be built specifically for being returned to the client, including any serialization or display decorations, etc. Nothing complicated here.

I think some people's first reaction is "I'm duplicating my effort if I have to create these classes" but you're really not as these classes serve a different purpose which is exactly what you're saying, separation of concerns.

```
public MyViewModel // model that is bound to the view
{
    private UserRepository _userRepo;
    public EmployeeDto ActiveUser {get;set;}

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        _userRepo = new UserRepository();
        LoadActiveUser();
    }

    private void LoadActiveUser()
    {
        var userId = (int)HttpContext.Current.Session["activeUser"] ?? 0;
        if(userId > 0)
        {
            ActiveUser = _userRepo.GetEmployee(userId);
        }
    }

}

public UserRepository
{
    private SomeEntityReference1 _myDal1;
    private SomeEntityReference2 _myDal2; // maybe you need to make some other data layer call in order to fill this object out

    public UserRepository()
    {
        _myDal1 = new SomeEntityReference1 ();
        _myDal2 = new SomeEntityReference2 (); 
    }

    public EmployeeDto GetEmployee(int id)
    {
        var empDto = new EmployeeDto();
        // get employee
        var dalEmpResult = _myDal.Employees.FirstOrDefault(e => e.EmployeeId == id);
        empDto.FirstName = dalResult.FName;
        empDto.LastName = dalResult.LName;
        empDto.Id = dalResult.EmployeeId;

        // get employee department info
        var dalDeptResult = _myDal2.Departments.FirstOrDefault(d => e.DepartmentId == dalEmpResult.DeptartmentId);
        empDto.DepartmentName = dalDeptResult.Name;

        return empDto;
    }
}

// client friendly employee object
[DataContract(Name="Employee")]
public class EmployeeDto
{
    public int Id {get; internal set;}

    [DataMember(Name="fname")]
    [DisplayName("Employee First Name:")]
    public string FirstName {get;set;}

    [DataMember(Name="lname")]
    [DisplayName("Employee Last Name:")]
    public string LastName {get;set;}   

    public int DeptId {get;set;}

    [DataMember(Name="dept")]
    [DisplayName("Works at:")]
    public string DepartmentName {get;set;}
}
```

The only reason I show two different EF references here (your database entity schemas) is just to illustrate that this would be your opportunity to do any "additional" processing before returning a FINISHED dto, ready for consumption.

Comment: So following your explanation, the DTO's the repository makes are the "Models" that sits in the Models folder in the MVC4 project ?

Comment: Yep. Generally, my models folder has at least 2 subfolders, dtos and viewmodels. My viewmodels are what I bind to the view and they contain any dtos that the will need. That should also honor the S in SOLID design. That is, the viewmodel's responsibility is providing the view with that data that it needs in the format it needs it in